# Использовать ли define('INSIDE', 'true'); в PHP?

Tags: php, безопасность

Собственно, есть ли практический смысл использования этого приёма защиты или можно не париться над этим?

Comment: к чему вообще этот define? Защита от чего? или лишняя строка ненужного кода?

Comment: Ну то есть использование в запрашиваемых напрямую файлах:

    define('INSIDE', 'true');

а в файлах, которые не должны быть доступны напрямую (типа библиотек) использовать что-то вроде:

    if (INSIDE != 'true') {exit;}

Я прочитал о таком.

Comment: ну можно итак.

Все понял тебя.

Тут скорее всего смотря какие цели преследуешь.

может в твоем случае и прокатит, я просто не сталкивался с таким, просто чем этот define будет отличаться от $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

В первом случае нужно подключать дополнительный файл во втором не нужно.  Первый удобен тем что поменял в одном месте и радуйся, во втором так не сделать. но часто ли меняется логика в приложении когда сегодня мне нужно открыть доступ напрямую а завтра нет?

Comment: Можно ли обойтись вообще без этой меры? Вообще, конечно, главная защита таких фйлов - disallowed в .htaccess, а описанный мной выше способ - это, как я понял, на случай уже сделанного взлома?

Comment: @Shrek это дельный способ защиты! Я удивился что ты не в курсе этого)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне приемлимо и даже советую, сам пользуюсь! Есть куча других **быдлопроверок**, но это лучше и чище всего!

Только конструктиву

```
if (INSIDE != 'true') {exit;}
```

лучше использовать как

```
defined('INSIDE') or die ('WTF');
```

Это мое личное мнение!

Comment: И вам спасибо)